# Facing Errors whlie using git push

Tags: git

I have connected to the remote repository two months ago and pushed files to that. (I use **windows** and **git Bash**)

Today, when I tried to push some code(which is almost 300MB) to the remote repository like

```
git push -u origin main
```

I got an error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'xxxx': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 21111 ms: Timed out
```

I have tried some solutions like reset `http.proxy`(https://blog.victorsilva.com.uy/failed-to-connect-to-github/) or set the `http.postbuffer` which didn't help, what should I do? Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:-

```
 >git config --global http.proxy XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:ZZ
```

where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the proxy server address and ZZ is the port number of the proxy server.

Comment: Actually, I have tried this solution. But still did not work.

Comment: then try to do this